# Retrofit + GSON + OkHttp + Okio libraries, no build errors, program doesn't work

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

My program doesn't have a build error, it works in Android Studio, but in Eclipse it always results to an error. I have included the libraries that it needs `Retrofit`, `GSON`, `okhttp` and `okio`.jars. I tried searching for the errors in the logcat though, no luck.. Maybe some of you knows the answer..

XML Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.checkaidev1.MainActivity" >


 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:hint="@string/email" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/confirm_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="13sp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:hint="@string/password" />

       <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:hint="@string/confirm_password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/insert_exam_item_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="@string/insert_exam_item"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/get_exam_item_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="@string/get_exam_item"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="13sp" /></LinearLayout>
```

Here is my controller.Java

```
package com.retrofit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RestAdapter;
import retrofit.converter.GsonConverter;
import retrofit.http.Body;
import retrofit.http.Field;
import retrofit.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit.http.GET;
import retrofit.http.Headers;
import retrofit.http.POST;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class CheckAideController {
    private RestAdapter mRestAdapter;
    private CheckAideInterface mCheckAideInterface;

    public CheckAideController() {
        mRestAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setConverter(new GsonConverter(new Gson()))
                .setEndpoint("http://checkaideapi.azurewebsites.net")
                .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
                .build();
        mCheckAideInterface = mRestAdapter.create(CheckAideInterface.class);
    }

    public void signIn(String email, String password, Callback<SignInObject> callback) {
        mCheckAideInterface.signIn("password", email, password, callback);
    }

    public void register(RegisterObject registerObject, Callback<SuccessObject> callback) {
        mCheckAideInterface.register(registerObject, callback);
    }

    public void insertExamItem(ExamItemObject examItemObject, Callback<SuccessObject> callback) {
        mCheckAideInterface.insertExamItem(examItemObject, callback);
    }

    public void getExamItemObjects(Callback<List<ExamItemObject>> callback) {
        mCheckAideInterface.getExamItemObjects(callback);
    }

    interface CheckAideInterface {

        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/token")
        void signIn(
                //concat "=password"
                @Field("grant_type") String grantType,
                @Field("UserName") String email,
                @Field("Password") String password,
                Callback<SignInObject> successObjectCallback);

        @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
        @POST("/api/Account/Register")
        void register(
                @Body RegisterObject registerObject,
                Callback<SuccessObject> successObjectCallback);

        @Headers({
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "Authorization: Bearer 4DbCWj-IWe4C4o8xiyeY5LIE8PLfNbmShqfKREW3v9GIqlavFnJPBZRyU2xgRx2k1eAlaMKu4x-Bmylca4gOKtDjLWJeI_IvqB7WwpU7Hn7Ef3IFPvThFPtGbV2SqB1_yJusTOtlEV8IDr491LiGyf74lzIbUbh9-ioNMpKSvtg5e3FPOyh1kd7dkhwRWpV5GHmO1AkQf3MEOi4KyuhpDh6WYXzlR4_-GsjJ8ZWSOtiO6VsvPc0s7GlP9WjWBOgn__SA3mCs0fZ2mSLSEvWpCYjWRtXQwORiv_9naQpUkw94XKguwUZ3st0ZpqdfXeSXsGUduedeeBO018qxvVeXHYoLtLoeVy330FwZLIA_Hp-S8rsIh9jXrElcDEsUzvCvgGogcmixQ8Azkzu95Wntp9p72I0CqfSCOLwtJBp_rZKwMvj8--V8AzwozKR6GOG2li91beITuJCM3j3qI64lLER8YeA9sf9463h-RFG1gyJ8XJf6m-1Cjgv4gWWtZHKH"
        })
        @POST("/api/Exam/InsertExam")
        void insertExamItem(
                @Body ExamItemObject examItemObject,
                Callback<SuccessObject> successObjectCallback);

        @Headers({
                "Content-Type: application/json",
                "Authorization: Bearer 4DbCWj-IWe4C4o8xiyeY5LIE8PLfNbmShqfKREW3v9GIqlavFnJPBZRyU2xgRx2k1eAlaMKu4x-Bmylca4gOKtDjLWJeI_IvqB7WwpU7Hn7Ef3IFPvThFPtGbV2SqB1_yJusTOtlEV8IDr491LiGyf74lzIbUbh9-ioNMpKSvtg5e3FPOyh1kd7dkhwRWpV5GHmO1AkQf3MEOi4KyuhpDh6WYXzlR4_-GsjJ8ZWSOtiO6VsvPc0s7GlP9WjWBOgn__SA3mCs0fZ2mSLSEvWpCYjWRtXQwORiv_9naQpUkw94XKguwUZ3st0ZpqdfXeSXsGUduedeeBO018qxvVeXHYoLtLoeVy330FwZLIA_Hp-S8rsIh9jXrElcDEsUzvCvgGogcmixQ8Azkzu95Wntp9p72I0CqfSCOLwtJBp_rZKwMvj8--V8AzwozKR6GOG2li91beITuJCM3j3qI64lLER8YeA9sf9463h-RFG1gyJ8XJf6m-1Cjgv4gWWtZHKH"
       })
        @GET("/api/Exam/GetExam")
        void getExamItemObjects(
                Callback<List<ExamItemObject>> successObjectCallback);
    }

    public class SuccessObject {
        @Expose
        private String success;

        public String getSuccess() {
            return success;
        }

        public void setSuccess(String success) {
            this.success = success;
        }
    }

    public class SignInObject {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("access_token")
        private String accessToken;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("token_type")
        private String tokenType;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("expires_in")
        private double expiresIn;
        @Expose
        private String userName;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName(".issued")
        private String issued;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName(".expires")
        private String expires;

        public String getAccessToken() {
            return accessToken;
        }

        public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
            this.accessToken = accessToken;
        }

        public String getTokenType() {
            return tokenType;
        }

        public void setTokenType(String tokenType) {
            this.tokenType = tokenType;
        }

        public double getExpiresIn() {
            return expiresIn;
        }

        public void setExpiresIn(double expiresIn) {
            this.expiresIn = expiresIn;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }

        public String getIssued() {
            return issued;
        }

        public void setIssued(String issued) {
            this.issued = issued;
        }

        public String getExpires() {
            return expires;
        }

        public void setExpires(String expires) {
            this.expires = expires;
        }
    }

    public class RegisterObject {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("Email")
        private String email;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("Password")
        private String password;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("ConfirmPassword")
        private String confirmPassword;

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getConfirmPassword() {
            return confirmPassword;
        }

        public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
            this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
        }
    }

    public class ExamItemObject {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("ExamName")
        private String examName;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("ItemNumber")
        private String itemNumber;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("CorrectKey")
        private String correctKey;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("ItemCategory")
        private String itemCategory;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("Results")
        private List<ItemObject> results = new ArrayList<>();

        public String getExamName() {
            return examName;
        }

        public void setExamName(String examName) {
            this.examName = examName;
        }

        public String getItemNumber() {
            return itemNumber;
        }

        public void setItemNumber(String itemNumber) {
            this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
        }

        public String getCorrectKey() {
            return correctKey;
        }

        public void setCorrectKey(String correctKey) {
            this.correctKey = correctKey;
        }

        public String getItemCategory() {
            return itemCategory;
        }

        public void setItemCategory(String itemCategory) {
            this.itemCategory = itemCategory;
        }

        public List<ItemObject> getResults() {
            return results;
        }

        public void setResults(List<ItemObject> results) {
            this.results = results;
        }
    }

    public class ItemObject {
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("StudentId")
        private String studentId;
        @Expose
        @SerializedName("AnsweredKey")
        private String answeredKey;

        public String getStudentId() {
            return studentId;
        }

        public void setStudentId(String studentId) {
            this.studentId = studentId;
        }

        public String getAnsweredKey() {
            return answeredKey;
        }

        public void setAnsweredKey(String answeredKey) {
            this.answeredKey = answeredKey;
        }
    }

}
```

It's a simple log-in and registration page.. With the according layout and MainActivity.Java

```
package com.retrofit;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import retrofit.Callback;
import retrofit.RetrofitError;
import retrofit.client.Response;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final CheckAideController checkAideController = new CheckAideController();
        Button signInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAideController.signIn("dennisintal@gmail.com", "P@$$w0rd", new Callback<CheckAideController.SignInObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(CheckAideController.SignInObject signInObject, Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        final EditText emailEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        final EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        final EditText confirmPasswordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.confirm_password);

        final Button registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);
        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckAideController.RegisterObject registerObject = checkAideController.new RegisterObject();
                registerObject.setEmail(emailEditText.getText().toString());
                registerObject.setPassword(passwordEditText.getText().toString());
                registerObject.setConfirmPassword(confirmPasswordEditText.getText().toString());

                checkAideController.register(
                        registerObject,
                        new Callback<CheckAideController.SuccessObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void success(CheckAideController.SuccessObject successObject, Response response) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Register Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });

        final Button insertExamItemButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.insert_exam_item_button);
        insertExamItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckAideController.ExamItemObject examItemObject = checkAideController.new ExamItemObject();
                examItemObject.setExamName("ANDROID EXAM");
                examItemObject.setItemNumber("1");
                examItemObject.setCorrectKey("A");
                examItemObject.setItemCategory("Some Category");

                List<CheckAideController.ItemObject> resultList = new ArrayList<CheckAideController.ItemObject>();
                CheckAideController.ItemObject itemObject1 = checkAideController.new ItemObject();
                itemObject1.setStudentId("1");
                itemObject1.setAnsweredKey("C");

                CheckAideController.ItemObject itemObject2 = checkAideController.new ItemObject();
                itemObject2.setStudentId("2");
                itemObject2.setAnsweredKey("A");

                resultList.add(itemObject1);
                resultList.add(itemObject2);
                examItemObject.setResults(resultList);

                checkAideController.insertExamItem(examItemObject, new Callback<CheckAideController.SuccessObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(CheckAideController.SuccessObject successObject, Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        final Button getExamItemButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_exam_item_button);
        getExamItemButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAideController.getExamItemObjects(new Callback<List<CheckAideController.ExamItemObject>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void success(List<CheckAideController.ExamItemObject> examItemObjects, Response response) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Get Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The Manifest also contains the permissions

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Logcat:

```
10-22 20:55:15.815: I/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find method okio.Source.close, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.createTunnel
10-22 20:55:15.815: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 11863: Lokio/Source;.close ()V
10-22 20:55:15.815: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x007b
10-22 20:55:15.825: E/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find class 'okio.Buffer', referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform.concatLengthPrefixed
10-22 20:55:15.825: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1604 (Lokio/Buffer;) in Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/Platform;
10-22 20:55:15.825: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
10-22 20:55:15.835: D/dalvikvm(25530): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2dfc at 0x02 in Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/Platform;.concatLengthPrefixed
10-22 20:55:16.135: I/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find method okio.Okio.source, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.<init>
10-22 20:55:16.135: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve static method 11860: Lokio/Okio;.source (Ljava/net/Socket;)Lokio/Source;
10-22 20:55:16.135: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000e
10-22 20:55:16.140: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lokio/BufferedSink;)
10-22 20:55:16.145: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lokio/ForwardingTimeout;)
10-22 20:55:16.145: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lokio/ForwardingTimeout;)
10-22 20:55:16.145: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lokio/BufferedSource;)
10-22 20:55:16.150: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lokio/ForwardingTimeout;)
10-22 20:55:16.150: I/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find method okio.ForwardingTimeout.delegate, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.detachTimeout
10-22 20:55:16.150: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 11849: Lokio/ForwardingTimeout;.delegate ()Lokio/Timeout;
10-22 20:55:16.150: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0000
10-22 20:55:16.160: I/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find method okio.BufferedSource.buffer, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.bufferSize
10-22 20:55:16.160: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 11811: Lokio/BufferedSource;.buffer ()Lokio/Buffer;
10-22 20:55:16.160: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-22 20:55:16.165: I/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find method okio.BufferedSink.flush, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.flush
10-22 20:55:16.165: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 11797: Lokio/BufferedSink;.flush ()V
10-22 20:55:16.165: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
10-22 20:55:16.175: I/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find method okio.BufferedSource.exhausted, referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.isReadable
10-22 20:55:16.175: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 11813: Lokio/BufferedSource;.exhausted ()Z
10-22 20:55:16.175: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0010
10-22 20:55:16.185: I/dalvikvm(25530): Failed resolving Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$ChunkedSink; interface 1615 'Lokio/Sink;'
10-22 20:55:16.185: W/dalvikvm(25530): Link of class 'Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$ChunkedSink;' failed
10-22 20:55:16.185: E/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find class 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSink', referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.newChunkedSink
10-22 20:55:16.185: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1297 (Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$ChunkedSink;) in Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection;
10-22 20:55:16.185: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0023
10-22 20:55:16.190: I/dalvikvm(25530): Failed resolving Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$AbstractSource; interface 1616 'Lokio/Source;'
10-22 20:55:16.190: W/dalvikvm(25530): Link of class 'Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$AbstractSource;' failed
10-22 20:55:16.190: W/dalvikvm(25530): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$ChunkedSource; (1296)
10-22 20:55:16.190: W/dalvikvm(25530): Link of class 'Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$ChunkedSource;' failed
10-22 20:55:16.195: E/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find class 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$ChunkedSource', referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.newChunkedSource
10-22 20:55:16.195: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1298 (Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$ChunkedSource;) in Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection;
10-22 20:55:16.195: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0023
10-22 20:55:16.195: I/dalvikvm(25530): Failed resolving Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink; interface 1615 'Lokio/Sink;'
10-22 20:55:16.195: W/dalvikvm(25530): Link of class 'Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink;' failed
10-22 20:55:16.195: E/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find class 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink', referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.newFixedLengthSink
10-22 20:55:16.195: W/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1299 (Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$FixedLengthSink;) in Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection;
10-22 20:55:16.195: D/dalvikvm(25530): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0023
10-22 20:55:16.200: I/dalvikvm(25530): Failed resolving Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$AbstractSource; interface 1616 'Lokio/Source;'
10-22 20:55:16.200: W/dalvikvm(25530): Link of class 'Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$AbstractSource;' failed
10-22 20:55:16.200: W/dalvikvm(25530): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource; (1296)
10-22 20:55:16.200: W/dalvikvm(25530): Link of class 'Lcom/squareup/okhttp/internal/http/HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource;' failed
10-22 20:55:16.200: E/dalvikvm(25530): Could not find class 'com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource', referenced from method com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.newFixedLengthSource
```

Comment: Are you using jar import on the OkHttp lib? Is so you should import also Okio (https://github.com/square/okio)

Comment: you are importing jars in android studio? all those libraries are available on maven central, you can get them directly from your gradle build file

Comment: It looks like mismatched versions of okhttp and okio libraries. What versions are you using?